# Как собрать и запустить примеры из SDK/NDK без Eclipse?

Tags: android

В поставке SDK/NDK есть хорошие примеры. Чтобы собрать их в Eclipse [нужно](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/index.html) установить плагин, импортировать проект, запустить сборку и выполнение. Как сделать то же самое из терминала?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример для HelloJNI. Нужно добавить пути к ndk-build и android в PATH и установить ant.

Перейти в папку проекта:

```
$ cd /path/to/hello-jni
```

Получить список целей:

```
$ android list targets
```

Обновить проект под цель (если нужная цель №1):

```
$ android update project --path . --target 1
```

Собрать C/C++ код:

```
$ ndk-build
```

Собрать Java-код:

```
$ ant release
```